# Is there a way I can change the color of my input placeholder text?

Tags: html, css, input, colors, placeholder

Everything can be found by reviewing the source code on http://trouver.sabalo.design, or the snippet below. :)

Im trying to get the placeholder text that says "Enter Code Here" to match the color of the button next to it that says "GO", and what it looks like when you enter something into the box.

When you enter something into the box, it looks the way I want "Enter Code Here" to look before someone starts typing.

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    -webkit-animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
            animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Trouver by SABALO</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://codepen.io/P1N2O/pen/xxbjYqx.css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
      <img src="/e1c85d81-b56f-41f3-bddb-634fe3bde046_200x200.png" style="background-color: white;">
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1 class="text-light">Trouver by SABALO</h1>
      <div class="btn-group mt-2 mb-4" role="group" aria-label="actionButtons">
         <input class="d-block btn btn-outline-light" type="text" id="code" placeholder="Enter Code Here"/><button class="d-block btn btn-outline-light" type="button" value="Go" onclick="redirectUser();">Go</button>
      </div>
      <h6 class="text-light small font-weight-bold"></h6>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha256-qM7QTJSlvtPSxVRjVWNM2OfTAz/3k5ovHOKmKXuYMO4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- partial -->
      <script>
         function redirectUser() {
         var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
         if(code == "0"){
           window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
         }
         else if(code == "1"){
           window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
         }
         else if(code == "2"){
           window.location.href = "https://www.bing.com/";
         }
         else{
           alert("Error: Code not found");
         }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::placeholder {color: red;}` to change color of placeholder for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+.

It will surely solve your problem but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Great, that changed the color of the placeholder, which is partially what I need this to do. I want it to act just like the "Go" button, which I have already set to have the background go white on hover and change the text black - also on hover. Everything worked fine on the go button, but I cant get the placeholder text to function the same.

Comment: @ourmoneycolorado Sad to know that I am not able to solve your issue completely but can you do me a favour that whenever you solve your issue please let me know how you solved it, I would love to know how you solved it and if I was able to help you even a little bit please accept and upvote my answer, it would mean a lot to me.

Comment: @ourmoneycolorado Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?